# SBJson - UTF8 characters

Tags: utf-8, sbjson

I have some data that contains UTF8 characters. If I do following I can able to see characters correctly in console:

```
NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithData:urlData
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response = %@", responseData);
```

Output

```
{"success":1,"row":1,"no":"001","title":"Arendi iOS","subject":"Konu 1","describtion":"Aciklama 1 ıİöÖçÇüÜğĞ","attachment":"Eklenti 1","status":1}
```

After this step I am doing this:

```
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary*)[jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
NSLog(@"jsonData = %@",jsonData);
```

Output:

```
jsonData = {
    attachment = "Eklenti 2";
    describtion = "Aciklama 2 \U0131\U0130\U00f6\U00d6\U00e7\U00c7\U00fc\U00dc\U011f\U011e";
    no = 002;
    row = 2;
    status = 1;
    subject = "Konu 2";
    success = 1;
    title = "Arendi Android";
}
```

After that I am doing this:

```
NSString *description = (NSString*)[jsonData objectForKey:@"description"];
```

But it gives me `null`. How can I print this characters correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether it is a simple typo but I couldn't help noticing that you had a field named "description" here.

> jsonData = {
>      attachment = "Eklenti 2";
>      describtion = "Aciklama 2 \U0131\U0130\U00f6\U00d6\U00e7\U00c7\U00fc\U00dc\U011f\U011e";
>      no = 002;
>      row = 2;
>      status = 1;
>      subject = "Konu 2";
>      success = 1;
>      title = "Arendi Android";
>   }

However in the final output, you were trying to get the value of a property named "description". If key is defined as "describtion", you can't find it by "description" and parser will return "null" as expected.

Hope it helps.